# Call a server side variable on client side in javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a javascript program that find the user and then it returns its _id on the server side. Is there the possibility to do the same thing on the client side? Or to call the server side variable on the client side WITHOUT using jquery? Here is my code:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
var post = req.body;
var query = User.where({userName : post.username});
query.findOne(function(err, user){
    if (err) { return err}
    if (user) {
        user.isValidPassword(post.password, function(n, isMatch){
            if(isMatch) {
                req.session.user_id = user._id;
                res.redirect('/library?' + user._id);
            } else{

                res.redirect('/login');
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.redirect('/login');
        }
    });
});
```

I did a function on the client side but I don't know why it just take the first user I have

```
function find2(){
var User = model.users[0]._id;
console.log(User);
}
```

In particular I want to call the variable user._id on the client side (as you can see, this is the server side). Is there a way to do it? Thanks :)

Comment: You have two choices - either embed the server variable in the HTML + JS response as the page is built, or make an AJAX request to get the server variable as needed from the client. The latter is a better approach IMO. See the http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ documentation.

Comment: Yep, reading your answer I thought the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... Wait... If I understand, you are trying to take a parameter from the path, is it right? Well, on client side you can do something like that:

```
function find2(){
    var User = window.location.href;
    var type = User.substr(User.indexOf("?")+1, User.length);
    console.log(type);
}
```

which, in case of a link like localhost:3000/library?dsds658dad it prints exactly dsds658dad

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the ability to call MongoDb using JS remotely, but you can use server side JS (for example node.js) which will get data from MongoDb and return on client as JSON as part of AJAX response.

Some JS frameworks (meteor.js, for example) can hide this work from you.

Here is an example from my project:

Server-side (node.js):

```
app.get('/api/info/:mode', function(req, res) {
  var mode = req.params.mode;
  console.log(mode);

  var process = function(err, questions) {
    if(!err) {
      var result = {};

      for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

        if(result.hasOwnProperty(questions[i].metagroup)) {
          var dict = result[questions[i].metagroup];
          if(dict.hasOwnProperty(questions[i].group)) {
            dict[questions[i].group] += 1;
          } else {
            dict[questions[i].group] = 1;
          }
          // result[questions[i].metagroup] = dict;
        }
        else {
          var dict = {};
          dict[questions[i].group] = 1;
          result[questions[i].metagroup] = dict;
        }
      }

      return res.send({ status: 'OK', info: result });
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 500;
      log.error('Internal error(%d): %s', res.statusCode, err.message);
      return res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
    }
  };

  if (mode == 'all') {
    return QuestionModel.find(process);
  } else {
    return QuestionModel.find({ priority_group: 1 }).exec(process);
  };
});
```

Client side (angular.js):

```
var requestGroupList = function(mode) {
            return $http.get("https://myhost/api/info/"+ mode)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            return response.data;
                        });
        };
```

Comment: Basically I want to store it in a variable on the client side. I don't understand very much your answer

Comment: Shortly, no - the AJAX request - response it the best way of doing.

Comment: The code you have posted is not enough to make the precise decision, but may be you get the only the first user, because you get the first element of array `model.users[0]`

Comment: no no model.users is already the first user I have. Then it is divided between data and tracks. So: user-->data;tracks-->[0]: username, last name, first name; [1]: album, artist...

Comment: Or may be because your code use query.findOne() method.  Anyway you must provide more information.  Which frameworks you use on the server side and client side, how do you get data from mongodb on the server side and how do you pass it on the client.

Comment: Good idea. Another way could be to call the data from seed.js. Is there the possibility to do that?

Comment: I have edit my answer and give you example from my project. Hope it helps you

Comment: I don't use jQuery in my example.

Comment: wait... what the $ is?

Comment: It is angular.js code. I have write in answer, but you can use any code to get AJAX request. It get the ordinary JSON.

Comment: Ok. I saw your code. Not sure it is the thing I need. Maybe this is more precise. Is there a way to call the variable in seed database?